# How to connect Orion with the public cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org instance using Cygnus

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

I am trying to persist my Orion data into the public *cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org* instance using Cygnus.
Cygnus is up and running and the *HDFSSink* part of my **/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf** looks like this:

`# OrionHDFSSink configuration
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.enable_grouping = false
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.backend_impl = rest
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = myUsernameInCosmosLabInstance
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_password = myPasswordInCosmosLabInstance
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = myTokenForCosmosLabInstance
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive = true
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.server_version = 2
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.host = cosmos.lablfi-ware.org
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.port = 10000
    cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.db_type = default-db`

I add a new subscription with Cygnus as the reference endpoint and I send an update to previously created NGSIEntity, but nothing appears in my *cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org* instance.
When looking at **/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log** I cant find nothing useful, and I find some Java errors.

I am using Orion v. 0.28 and Cygnus v. 0.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log is saying:

```
Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://cosmos.lablfi-ware.org:10000/default: java.net.UnknownHostException: cosmos.lablfi-ware.org
```

You must configure the right Hive endpoint:

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
```

Instead of:

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.host = cosmos.lablfi-ware.org
```

NOTE: Youy may have noticed I've used `cosmos.lab.fiware.org`. Both `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org` are valid, bit the first one is preferred.

Comment: Thanks @frb! The data is successfully created as a table in hive in the cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org instance. I was wondering, shouldn´t it be created also as a file? I see this line in the log, but no file is created in my user´s folder: `function=persistAggregation | Persisting data at OrionHDFSSink. HDFS file (def_serv/def_servpath/Room1_Room/Room1_Room.txt)` and I can´t find this **Room1_Room.txt** file anywhere.

Comment: Such a file should be under your Cosmos user space, i.e. under `hdfs://user/josecastillolema/`. In fact, is is there (I've seen it as super user): `# hadoop fs -ls /user/josecastillolema/def_serv/def_servpath/Room1_Room/Room1_Room.txt
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 josecastillolema josecastillolema       6098 2016-03-06 21:51 /user/josecastillolema/def_serv/def_servpath/Room1_Room/Room1_Room.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To find the data that Orion was persisting in my Cosmos global instance:

1. From *Hadoop*:

`# hive
   hive> select * from myUsernameInCosmosLabInstance_def_serv_def_servpath_room1_room_column;`

2. Alternative method:

`# hadoop fs -ls /user/myUsernameInCosmosInstance/def_serv/def_servpath/Room1_Room/Room1_Room.txt`